# Two different kinds of p values in gtsummary?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have this big database with 6700 cases and 90 variables. For simplicity, consider three variables `Sex`, `Age`, and `mortality`. Age is categorical with intervals 18-39, 40-49,... In `gt_summary`, this is part of the [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL7IO.png) I made that showed mortality for males and females, stratified for the different age categories (data redacted due to confidentiality of the study). Code to make the table:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

tbl_mortality_low_merged <- df %>%
  select(Sex, Age, mortality ) %>%
   
  tbl_strata(Age, ~
                tbl_summary(
                 .x,
                  by=Sex,
                  label= list( Age = "Age categories", mortality),
                  statistic= all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                  missing_text = "Missing values",
                 value = list(mortality = "Dead")
                ) %>%
               add_p() %>%
               modify_caption("**Table 2. Mortality stratified for sex and age, and low age categories merged**") %>%
                bold_labels()
                
)

tbl_mortality_low_merged
```

`add_p` gives me the p-value of the chi² for possible significance between the sexes in the age categories, and that's good because I want that. But I also want one p-value (also a chi² test) telling if there is significance over all the age categories i.e. if certain age categories have a higher mortality than others.

Simply adding two `add_p`-commands doesn't work. I'm trying to use base R's `chisq.test` to find out the p-value for starters (I'm an R-rookie), but even when I find how to do that, I don't know how to add that to the table.

If `gt_summary` doesn't support this, are there other packages that do?

Any time taken or comments and answers written are greatly apreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will get you the table you're after!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.2'

# build stratified table
tbl1 <-
  trial |> 
  select(grade, trt, response) |> 
  tbl_strata(
    strata = grade, 
    ~ .x |> 
      tbl_summary(
        by = trt,
        missing = "no"
      ) |> 
      add_p()
  )

# build an unstratified table
tbl2 <- 
  trial |> 
  select(trt, response) |> 
  tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no") |> 
  add_p()


# combine the tables
tbl_final <-
  tbl_merge(list(tbl1, tbl2), tab_spanner = FALSE) |> 
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2023-09-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This would have been the code if I wanted to know if there is a significance in male/female-mortality without taking into account the ages. I want to know, however, is there is a significance in the ages-mortality without taking into account the sexes.
Nevertheless was your code a tremendous help in finding the solution. All I had to do was, in tbl2, changing the `by`-function in `tbl_summary` from `trt` to `grade`.

Comment: Now [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMEpG.jpg) this is the table. It's quite wide though. Any way to get "tbl2" above the sex-stratification of tbl1? (Should I post a new Q for that?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73902909/add-multiple-levels-of-headers-to-gtsummary-regression-table-with-many-models/73903070#73903070